Plotting distribution of lmer multilevel t-values or p-values
I have a 2-level multilevel model with level 1 being "day" and level 2 being "participant". I have set up the followng model:
mlm3 <- mom_MH_CS ~ 1 + CR_unpl_4items_MC + CR_pl_4items_MC + nr_entry + day_sitnumberneg_MC + day_sitnumberpos_MC + grandmean_NA_unpl + grandmean_PA_pl + trait_gender + ( 1 + CR_unpl_4items_MC + CR_pl_4items_MC |vp_initials)  
mlm3 <- lmer( mlm3, data = mds, REML = TRUE )
summary( mlm3 )

Now I would like to

rerun this model for every single participant and have this data
then be displayed in a distribution of t-values or p-values (y-axis), with the participants (name of the variable: vp_initials) filling up the x-axis

How could I accomplish this?
Best regards and thank you very much in advance for your valuable suggestions
Erefin
